# Offset LVM mount

Tags: mount, lvm, dd

I have some ext4 and LVM partitions on a disk. I executed `dd` to dump this disk content to a file.
Now I can mount ext4 partition by using offset but don't know the way to mount the LVM partition.

What is the command to mount the LVM partition from `dd` file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could create a loop device out of the image. LVM should be able to automatically detect all the VGs and LVs. Then you can mount/change whatever you want. Use `lsblk` and `vgs` or `lvs` to check what was detected.
Example:

```
lodev=$(losetup -f --show -P $YOURIMAGEFILE)
```

If you don't need the partitions/LVs/filesystems anymore you can unmount everything, deactivate the VGs of the image and delete the loop device.

```
vgchange -a n $YOURVG
losetup -d "$lodev"
```